# Pictures into Jar

Tags: java

In my game I have the following code:

> ```
>    public Main() {
>                 p = new Potato();
>                 addKeyListener(new AL());
>                 setFocusable(true);
>                 ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/test.png");
>                 img = i.getImage();
>                 time = new Timer(5, this);
>                 time.start();
>                 en = new Enemy(700, 200, "C:/enemy.png");
>                 en2 = new Enemy(700, 200, "C:/enemy.png");
>         }
> ```

However I would like to put test.png inside of the package, but when I do it creates errors with the i piece. I want to put the images inside of a folder inside the jar file, but then what would I put in there place? I'm mainly asking how do I make ImageIcons reference files inside of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give a path relative to your class file location.

Read more on using relative paths :

[Java- relative path of text file in main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281428/java-relative-path-of-text-file-in-main)

[relative path in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259773/relative-path-in-java)

[How to define a relative path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209085/how-to-define-relative-path-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIcon(String)` expects a a File reference. When you embedded you resources into the application context (and them it the Jar), they can no longer be accessed liked files, instead, y need to use something like `getClass().getResource(...)`

For example, assuming that the image is in the same package as the class, you could use...

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("test.png"));
```

Or if the image is in another package, you might need to use

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to /resource/test.png"));
```